# SAP HANA Export Statement

Tags: stored-procedures, export, hana

In the [SAP Documentation is an EXPORT](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/1.0.12/en-US/c65b43769b4c4038a6a6e662c726575f.html) statement described.

Unfortunately I have the following error in a stored procedure:

> Syntax error in procedure object: incorrect syntax near '#': line 18 col 8 (at pos 487)

Line 18 is:

```
EXPORT #MY_EXPORT AS CSV INTO '/path/filename' with replace;
```

[image]

**How to fix this?**

Full SQL

```
PROCEDURE "MY_SCHEMA"."my.package::EXPORTCVINTOCSV" ( ) 
    LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
    DEFAULT SCHEMA MY_SCHEMA
    AS
BEGIN


--create local temporary table #MY_EXPORT as (
create table MY_EXPORT as (
SELECT a.* 
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."my.package/myView" a
    JOIN "_SYS_BIC"."my.package/myOtherView" b
        ON a."CheckID" = b."CheckID"
WHERE a."SchedulingID" IS NOT NULL
);

EXPORT MY_EXPORT AS CSV INTO '/my/export/path' with replace;   

END;
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code as text, not as image, and as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @SandraRossi I added the full SQL as text (anonymized packages, view-names, paths)

Comment: Not sure temporary table works but can you try enclosing the name with double quotes ?

Comment: @AbdelDadouche OK that's why I created a normal table as well (see the code below!)

Answer (score 1):

for unknown reasons IMPORT & EXPORT are not supported as procedure body, but as workaround you can wrap them into exec, .e.g.

```
EXEC 'EXPORT MY_EXPORT AS CSV INTO ''/my/export/path'' with replace';
```

Answer (score 0):

the error message is confusing, but export of local temporary tables is anyway not supported.
If you try such statement outside the procedure you get:
`SQL Error [7] [HY000]: SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: cannot export local temporary table #MY_EXPORT`

Comment: OK this is what I already ruled out by creating a regular table. The question is why is it not working with a normal table.